# PHP Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /var/www/toolbox

Tags: php

I have data in DB like this showmember,memberform,newmember,editmemform I want to check the checkbox if the value is in array.

[Data in DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH7VJ.png)

[Checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlND5.png)

```
$ret = mysqli_query($db_conn," SELECT * FROM gt_accesslist WHERE GP_ID = $id");
if(!$ret)
{
    echo mysqli_error($db_conn);
    exit;
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ret))
{
    $checked = 'checked="checked"';
    $accValues = explode(',', $row['ACL_NAME']);

}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' name='items[]' value='showmember' "; if (in_array('showmember',$accValues)){ echo $checked;} echo"> Show Member
```

Comment: I think error was more predictive.. check $accValues is null or not before passing to in_array function

Comment: Where is $accValues defined?

Comment: while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ret))
{
    $checked = 'checked="checked"';
    $accValues = explode(',', $row['ACL_NAME']);

}

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type='checkbox' name='items[]' value='showmember' <?php if (is_array($accValues) && in_array('showmember',$accValues)){ echo $checked;} ?>> Show Member
```